# Get receiver of the chain from sender context

Tags: smalltalk, callstack, pharo

Imagine I have a method like

```
someMethod

  ^ instVar class getProperty
```

Can I somehow implement the `getProperty`method in a way

```
getProperty

  thisContext sender ...
```

to get the object to which `class` is being sent? I'e value of `instVar` but without knowing that it's an instance variable, maybe it is a parameter or a literal in some other cases.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What Leandro said. Isn't this your method, i.e. wouldn't you know whether `instVar` is an instance variable? Are you looking to do some form of IoC?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obvious, instVar is no more on the execution stack, it's been replaced by the return value of message 'class'.

Maybe you could cheat and instrument all senders of 'class getProperty' chain to do something special like replacing with 'MyAnalyzer getClassPropertyOf: instVar'. It sounds like evil.

Answer (score 1):

This is horrible and probably won't work in all cases, but may give you a starting point if you absolutely have to do this (and is also a nice demonstration of the level of reflectivity possible in Smalltalk):

```
getProperty 

    | sender message receiver |

    sender := thisContext sender.
    message := sender method abstractBytecodeMessageAt: (sender pc - 3).

    message selector = #pushReceiverVariable: ifTrue: [receiver := sender receiver instVarAt: (message arguments first + 1)].
    message selector = #pushTemporaryVariable: ifTrue: [receiver := sender tempAt: (message arguments first + 1)].
    message selector = #pushConstant: ifTrue: [receiver := message arguments first].

    receiver isNil ifTrue: [self error: 'unknown'].

    ^receiver
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you refactor someMethod as follows?

```
someMethod

  ^ instVar class getPropertyOf: instVar
```

Comment: Sadly no, this is why I want to traverse contexts, as I cannot change the existing code, and there are plenty of usages like this in the system.

Answer (score 0):

You could instrument the slots to return a wrapper or proxy when answering to `class`. The proxy would know the object held by the slot.

Comment: Does it work if instVar is not an instance variable?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I thought I'd mention it anyway, in case that instance variables are always involved.